# Cannot log into vSphere Client from VM within same host

Tags: vmware-esxi, vsphere-client

I log into the esxi host with vsphere 5.5 just fine.

I then select my server 2008 R2 vm and login through the console.

Once I get in the server, where I have vsphere client installed, I try to connect via the IP of the host, it shows it cannot connect. I have searched and only found issues similar to this revolving around firewall ports not being open, but all the ports needed are open. Everything is default.

[Login Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gZpe.png)

[vSwitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTuCY.png)

Comment: Do you mind if I ask what you are trying to achieve here? I am curious as to why you want to connect to the management interface inside a guest. J

Comment: So i can upload files from a synolgy drive to the datastore

Comment: Let's see your vswitch layout then

Comment: So you're logging into the vSphere console so that you can connect to a VM and log into the vSphere console from that VM so that you can upload a file from a Synology NAS to the datastore? Why not just upload it directly?

Comment: I cannot upload from my local computer as I am not local to the server in question. The only one I know how to do it is to pull from the storage and upload from the local vm

Comment: @Chopper3 is this what your talking about ?

Comment: Yeah, that's fine, what about showing us the IP/netmask/defaultgateway of both the host and the VM please - also why do you only have one uplink???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hello,**

I was facing issue close to this. The issue was resolved via rebuilding network in VM and at ESXi host thus some gateways was unaccepted for nested connection to vSphere.

One more tip try to go with web client just to ascertained that problem in connections.

Comment: I also cannot get access to the Web GUI for vSphere from within a VM on the host